# babel with browerify causing syntax error with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify

First of all I'm using gulp

Compile my bundle with browserify and babel

```
var bundler = browserify(filepath, args)
    .plugin(watchify, {ignoreWatch: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/bower_components/**']})
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
```

this is what I get when I try to run the command

```
SyntaxError: browser/components/table.js: Unexpected token (50:14)
  48 |  }
  49 | 
> 50 |  handleToggle = () => this.setState({ drawer: !this.state.drawer })
     |               ^
  51 | 
  52 |  status(entry) {
  53 |      if (entry.status === undefined) {
```

Everything other than arrow functions seem to work perfectly, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

```
export default class TableHandler extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {drawer: true}
 }
 handleToggle = () => this.setState({ drawer: !this.state.drawer })
 render(){
  return(
    <Drawer docked={false} width={300} open={this.state.drawer} />
  )
 }
}
```

there is more code, but I thought this might be enough

Comment: Can you post the full code? It looks like you want `handleToggle: () =>` if that's an object property.

Comment: Is this inside a class declaration? You can't use arrow functions in classes, as you can only set methods, not properties, in class declarations, and it wouldn't have the right `this` anyway.

Comment: you should add babel-preset-stage-0 , check https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&code=class%20PostInfo%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%09handleOptionsButtonClick%20%3D%20(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7BshowOptionsModal%3A%20true%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false

Comment: @Utro why does OP need to add stage0 preset? Arrow functions are part of ES2015, class fields is stage 2 proposal.

Comment: arrow func in class is not in ES2015

Comment: @Utro It works for me **without** stage0. See [this example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Cstage-1&code=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20handler%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('arrow%20func%20in%20class!!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Aa.handler()%3B&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false)

Comment: Indeed , you have selected stage-1 )))

Comment: @Utro it works without stage0. So why do you tell OP to enable stage0? I guess babel presets will be updated shortly to include recent proposal advances so it will work with just stage 2. Moreover, I would recommend to enable only this specific proposal instead of adding stage1/2 presets

Answer (score 5):

Alright after adding 'stage-1' I was able to use arrow functions without any issues.

```
.transform(babelify, {presets: ['es2015', 'stage-1', 'react']})
```